# Has Microsoft Fixed Linq to Entities Performance Problems in .NET 4.0?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, .net-4.0

I feel pretty comfortable with the entity framework now. I have been reading some performance articles on the Linq to Entities performance issues. Are these issues still present in .NET 4.0?

Comment: Will help if you specify which performance issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Entity Framework performance is much better in EF 4.0 than in previous releases.

However, much (most?) of the EF performance issues are related to the specific [ADO.NET Entity Framework Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dd363565.aspx) you are using.  It's up to the provider to handle the requests in a way that performs well for that database engine.  SQL Server does well - many other providers, not so well.

This is true in the current release of EF, as well.  For example, some of the providers create many, many more database calls than necessary, which becomes especially problematic in 3.5 due to the way EF is accessing data in certain cases.

Comment: @luke 101: The real name of "Linq to Entities" is actually ADO.NET Entity Framework.  That was exactly what I was talking about.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399567.aspx